# How to parse json and display a different color in HTML table depending on value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

**Scenario:**
I am taking data from an external json file, parsing it, and then appending it to an        HTML table that is using the footable jquery plug-in.

**Question:**
This is a total noob question......but does anyone know (or could provide an example of) how to use javascript to parse that json file....and depending on the value of one of the name/value pairs, display that text in a different color within the table? Currently, everything is displaying in plain text.

COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS is the object that I would like to display differently depending on the value. So I would need something like....

if COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "Mild exacerbation"......display in green, bold text

if COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "Moderate exacerbation"......display in yellow, bold text

if COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "Severe exacerbation"......display in red, bold text

Below is the way I currently have the data appending the table. Can anyone help with incorporating an if / condition to accomplish the above? Do I need to add it within my createPatientTable function?

```
if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost') {
    console.log('local');
  $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url  : 'json/gtw_copd_mpage3.json',
  dataType : 'json',
   success : function(json) {

        createPatientTable(json);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
        });
}else{
    var getPatients = new XMLCclRequest();
    getPatients.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (getPatients.readyState == 4 && getPatients.status == 200) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(getPatients.responseText);
            createPatientTable(json);
    };
}
};

});


function createPatientTable(json) {
$.each(json.LIST, function(i, COPD_QUAL) {
    $('.footable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + COPD_QUAL.PATIENT + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.FIN +'</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.NURSE_UNIT + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ROOM + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.BED +'</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ATTENDING_PHYS + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.LENGTH_OF_STAY + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS + '</td></tr>');
});
$('.footable').footable();
};
```

Here is one of the json arrays within the file:

```
{"COPD_QUAL":"15","LIST":[   {"PATIENT":"TEST, TRICKLE","FIN":"70100905","NURSE_UNIT":"TIC","ROOM":"C219","BED":"A","ATTENDING_PHYS":"LEVITEN , DANIEL L","LENGTH_OF_STAY":"161days 20:15:24","MED_ASSESS":"Mild exacerbation"}...
```

Comment: Please, indent your code better so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
/* ... */
+ '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.LENGTH_OF_STAY + 
'</td><td class="assessment ' + getSeverity(COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS) + '">' + 
COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS + '</td></tr>')
```

with

```
getSeverity = (function() {
    var lookup = {
        "Mild exacerbation": "mild",
        "Moderate exacerbation": "moderate",
        "Severe exacerbation": "severe" // presumably you didn't mean two milds...
    };
    var defaultValue = "unknown"
    return function(assessment) {
        return lookup[assessment] || defaultValue;
    };
}());
```

and CSS like:

```
.assessment {font-weight: bold;}
.mild {color: green;}
.moderate {color: yellow;}
.severe {color: red;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback everyone! I'm giving it a shot now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add an if condition that attaches a class to the appropriate row:

```
var class = '';
if(COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "Mild exacerbation"){
    class = 'mild';
} else if (COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "Moderate exacerbation") {
    class = 'moderate';
} else if (COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS == "??? exacerbation") {
    class = 'severe';
}
```

then change your tr to:

```
"<tr class="' + class + '">...
```

And set up the styling for .mild, .moderate, .severe in a CSS file.

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Though they probably don't want this style on the whole row so it should be added to the respective cell (`td` element).

Comment: Beat me to it, but this is a client-side Javascript AJAX response, not a PHP one.  So your string concatenation code is off...

Comment: wouldn't you need to use this syntax `<tr class="' + class + '">` instead? Me thinks that the PHP syntax wouldn't work in JS :P